# Jmeter how to start with an amount of visitors, add visitors every 5 minutes and end with an amount of visitors

Tags: jmeter

I need to start with 90 visitors.  Every 5 minutes I have to add 90 visitors. So that you run with 990 visitors in the last 5 minutes.

How can I achieve this?  What do I need to fill in where?  I want to use Concurrency Thread group but never used it

I have in the thread group: 1 http cache manager, 1 http cooking manager, a unifor Random timer and 11 links to target (HTTP Request).

Thank you for your great help.

Is this the right way to fill it in?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you "want to use the [Concurrency Thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)" go ahead and use it, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) as a part of **Custom Thread Groups** bundle.

Here is example configuration

[image]

if doing some simple path is too complex for you you can go for [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/), it might be easier somehow:

[image]